# Book about creating geometries with programming languages

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm a programmer, i create software, i was searching for a book with a practical approach about geometry and how to create shapes.

Probably i'm searching for a book with some practical algorith about linear algebra; I really don't know, but i know that i'm looking for a practical approach for real-world computation, i'm pretty sure i'm not looking for some fractal just for nerding around :P.

My favourite language is C++, if this can drive you to a more specific aid.

EDIT: especially about 3D figures, about convex shapes, fields, vectors, something like that.

Comment: Quit nerding around, nerd! Being curious about the world around us never got anyone *anywhere*. (Just sarcasm of course, see answer below.)

Comment: You might get better answers if you ask this on one of the programming stackexchanges.

Comment: I think you question is quite generic. Anyway you can consider the John Vince's books for computer graphics.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.ics.ele.tue.nl/~heco/courses/Computation/OOP_c++_tutorial.pdf

Comment: Not C++ but have a look at [Mathematical Illustrations:
A Manual of Geometry and PostScript](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/graphics/manual/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched around for geometry programs written in C++? Being the good programmer that you are, you will probably get some ideas from the sourcecode.

The first one I ran across appears to be called [Blitz3D](http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=42657).

Comment: thank you for your hint but C++ code == specific implementation of an algorithm, the algorithm is something derived from mathematical laws in my case, if i had to follow your advice I'd be simply ignoring 2 fundamental steps.

Comment: @user827992 Then when you write your question, ask for *laws*, and then don't write that you're looking for *"some practical algorithms"*.